# Using mutate with function that includes nth row value

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I am wondering if it is possible to use `dplyr`'s `mutate` function to add a new column to a data frame that is a function of multiple row values from other columns. For example, if I had a data frame `df` with columns `a` and `b` and wanted to make a new column `c`, where `c = a[n] + b[n +1]`, can I use `mutate` with a `for` loop?

I tried the below code but it didn't work:

```
  for(n in 1:nrow(df)){
        df %>%
              mutate(c = a[n] + b[n + 1])    
  }
```

Comment: What is variable `n`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you're probably looking for it `lead`, to get a view of `b` offset by one record.  Then the command would be

```
df %>% mutate(c=a + lead(b, 1))
```

For example,

```
> data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10) %>% mutate(c = a + lead(b, 1))
    a  b  c
1   1  1  3
2   2  2  5
3   3  3  7
4   4  4  9
5   5  5 11
6   6  6 13
7   7  7 15
8   8  8 17
9   9  9 19
10 10 10 NA
```